# How to access data of mother class from child class?

Tags: c++, class, architecture, instance

How can I access data of the mother class from a child class without creating an instace?
I've got something like:

```
#include <iostream>
class mother {
    private:

    public:
        mother(){}
        virtual ~mother(){}
        virtual void func() const {std::cout << "mother " << dat <<std::endl;}
        virtual void dat_set(std::string arg){dat=arg;}
        std::string dat;
};

class child:mother {
    public:
        child(){}
        ~child(){}
        void dat_set(std::string const arg) override { mother::dat_set(arg); }
        void func() const override { std::cout << "child " << mother::dat << std::endl; }
};

int main (void) {
    auto tmp = new mother();
    tmp->dat_set("test");
    auto foo = new child();
    foo->func();
}
```

How do I make sure that `func()` invoked by `foo` gets access to the data stored in `mother`?

**EDIT**
Should I not be able to make `std::string dat` a `static std::string dat`? I tried that but I get compiler errors along the lines of

```
/tmp/ccZV7Y4n.o: In function `child::func()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5child4funcEv[_ZN5child4funcEv]+0x1d): undefined reference to `mother::dat[abi:cxx11]'
```

Comment: Note that when `child` inherits `mother`, an instance of `mother` gets created, you don't need to make your own. You can simply call `child.data_set("hi");` and `child.func()` to see the access. Note you probably will need to publically inherit `mother` like so `class child : public mother`

Comment: . o O ( since inheritance models a "is a"-relationship a child inheriting from mother would only make sense for female children )

Comment: Uh, do you **have** to use pointers (in classes!?)... even if you want them so badly... use [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or something like that... The only reason pointers exist in C++ nowadays is to modify the variable in a function call or for something which they call ***C** arrays*... But that too has been replaced by usage of references and vectors...

Comment: besides: Your destructors should be `virtual`. If they aren't, they won't get properly called if you try to `delete` an object of a derived `class` using a base-`class` pointer.

Comment: @Swordfish The destructors don't even have anything inside of them in the first place... Why not do `virtual ~mother() = default;` because you know, style matters...

Comment: @Ruks That was meant as a general advice. That it is pointless for empty dtors is obvious.

Comment: @Ruks: "I don't think destructors should even have a body if they are supposed to be kept empty with curly braces..." So do I.

Comment: I don't think destructors should even have a body if they are supposed to be kept empty with curly braces... (That is where default comes in...) Something simple like `virutal ~mother() { delete this; }` is acceptable...

Comment: @Ruks "`virutal ~mother() { delete this; }`" ... if you like Stack Overflow(s) ...

Comment: @Swordfish `virtual ~mother() = default;` if you don't like them...

Comment: @Rusk Sorry Rusk, but i don't see the point in giving me all these tips??

Comment: *How can I access data of the mother class from a child class without creating an instace?* I don't quite understand the question. If you want data of `mother` then you have to instantiate it. Do you want `foo->func()` to print `"test"` instead of `"mother"`? Is that what you meant by that?

Comment: @DeanSeo correct, that's what I'm looking for... I've updated my code above

Comment: @Ruks I've updated my code with your suggestions but the question stays the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The trick to accessing functions inside base classes from derived classes is to redeclare them using *virtual* and *override* specifiers...

First, make the destructor [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)... (*Since your compiler doesn't want virtual functions inside a class without a virtual destructor*)

```
virtual ~mother() = default; // If the compiler is happy, we all are happy...
```

**And then make your functions virtual...**

```
virtual void dat_set(std::string const arg) { dat = arg; }
virtual void func() const { std::cout << "mother " << dat << std::endl; }
```

> **You have to define it again inside the child class since the child cannot *become* the mother, and that is the reason you cannot access those functions...**

```
void dat_set(std::string const arg) override { mother::dat_set(arg); }
void func() const override { mother::func(); }
```

Here you ***have to have the exact same declaration you had in the base class*** (except *virtual* which is redundant when *override* is used...) and add [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier that re-declares the same function you had in the base class inside the child class...

For behavior just put `mother::func()` (*`mother::dat_set(/*params go here*/)` for calling the function with parameters, and I bet you might already know that*) to call the respective function...

> **Note:** The override specifier (since **C++11**) is similar to the virtual specifier, except that it is only usable in dervied classes/structures, and makes the usage of virtual inside child declarations optional (In your base class you have to use virtual instead)...

---

**Edit:** You can assign a derived class to a base class but it is not possible to do the opposite, and that is the reason why your code fails... A close attempt to doing something like this would be the usage of namespaces, for example:

```
namespace some_namespace
{
    static std::string dat;
    // The child and mother class declarations and other things go here...
}
```

---

Kind regards,

*Ruks.*

Comment: But even with these changes applied, child still does not get access to `mother`'s `std::string dat`

Comment: @cerr That is because a child cannot access members having the `private` specifier... I think you mixed it with [`protected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access)...

Comment: I've moved `std::string dat;` now into `public:`, couldf use `protected` too

Comment: @cerr Do you run into any problems now?

Comment: yes, `foo->func()` isn't getting the value set by `tmp->dat_set`. See https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20be6da04a83bb4b

Comment: No no no... You have to know that the variable *mother* and *child* are different variables... see closely... You haven't initialized `dat` *inside of the child variable*... Do something like [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea93cd2d44ee615e)...

Comment: but what I need is that data set to mother is visible to it's child... how do I do this?

Comment: Ah, then do [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eae9b002c7dd25f), it assigns the mother to the child, what you probably wanted... Also, best option, has been advised before as well, stop using *new* specifier here, has no importance in this piece of code and just forces you to [dereference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182155/discussion-between-cerr-and-ruks).